# Why did installing Crosswalk affect non Intel XDK app

Tags: android, cordova, webrtc, opentok, crosswalk-runtime

I am currently try to find a viable option to incorporate webRtc into an Android & ios app using Cordova /phonegap/ionic and I have tried getting the following examples to work but till recently I have had no luck:

https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok

https://github.com/gomobile/sample-webrtc-video-client

https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc
(phoneRtc was an issue only because it had no working examples and I found the docs lacking)
I was able to get the 1st two deployed correctly with no issue but every time I did so I could not get a video feed from my camera, all I got was the following:

OpenTok plugin:

[image: OpenTok plugin]

Intel XDK sample-webrtc-video-client:

[image]

When I tried to Debug the OpenTok app I the following error:

```
OT.exception :: title: Connection Failed (1013) msg: Publisher PeerConnection Error: The video stream failed to connect. Please notify the site owner if this continues to happen.
```

and when I tried to debug the Intel XDK example It prompeted me to install `Intel App Preview` and when it relaunched the sample App to debug it prompted me to update `Intel App Preview Crosswalk` and then the App worked...

What's confusing me is now the OpenTok app also works....Can someone shed some light on this?
did this install some global library or something? I have tried googling this but cannot seem to find an explaination that helps me to understand how or why this happens as I saw no mention of Crosswalk in the OpenTok application.

Comment: I can assure you that OpenTok has no dependency on anything inside the Intel XDK or Crosswalk. The `Connection Failed` error usually has to do with network problems. Is the Session a routed or a relayed session? Were you subscribing to the stream from the same device or another device/browser?

Comment: @Ankur Actually This is just the local media from the camera I am referring to on Android.

Comment: @Ankur Also, a little of topic but I have also found the latest OpenTok does not work in Chrome (latest version) either on Mac or Windows, where would I submit information about this?

Comment: Would you be able to provide the entire LogCat from the application, perhaps in a link to a gist.github.com? Which site were you using to check OpenTok in Chrome on Mac/Windows? Please try https://opentokrtc.com. We've not had any other reports of that issue.

Comment: Don't have the log can't unfortunately and can't reproduce

Comment: Thanks, at this point there isn't much else we can do. If I hear about anything similar, I'll come back to add details.